# Variável declarada no viewDidLoad não é encontrada no Botão - Swift 2

Tags: array, string, swift

Tenho uma array que gera uma palavra ao carregar o `viewController`, e salva uma posição aleatória na variável declarada na `viewDidLoad` ou antes dentro da class. Mas dentro do botão não acha a variável para receber e utilizar o conteúdo.

aqui somente o código gerando a palavra aleatória do array que funciona perfeitamente:

```
let palavra: Array = ["ABC", "DEF"]
let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(palavra.count)))
let string = Array(palavra.characters)
```

depois só preciso fazer uma comparação dentro do botão, quero comparar uma string digitada, comparando cada letra da string com cada letra da palavra digitada. Então pensei em gerar um array e percorrer as posições comparando.

mas dentro do botão não reconhece a variável ja criada.

obrigado
Fernando.

Comment: Olá Fernando, fica mais fácil de lhe ajudar se você postar o código ao qual você se refere na pergunta. Você pode editar sua pergunta e colocar o código relevante sem a necessidade de criar uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

O que possivelmente está ocorrendo é um problema de escopo:

Uma variável (ou uma constante `let`) declarada no corpo de uma função somente será acessível dentro dela (neste caso, da `func viewDidLoad()`).

Ao mover a declaração para um nível acima (no nível da classe) você conseguirá utilizar esta variável ou constante dentro da `viewDidLoad`.

Algo como:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {    

    @IBOutlet var myButton : UIButton!

    let palavra: Array = ["ABC", "DEF"]
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(palavra.count)))
    let minhaString = Array(palavra.characters)

    func viewDidLoad() {
        self.myButton.text = minhaString
       }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado! :)